# Writing a custom INF for WinUSB driver package installation targetting windows8 64 bit OS

Tags: wix, winusb

I have a simple user mode usb driver that is installing and working fine in Windows XP 32 bit,Windows 7 32 & 64 bit and windows 8 32 bit. but for some reason fails to install correctly in Windows 8 64 bit.  The inf file i use is listed below:

I get an error like "error encountered while installing driver package"

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; USB.INF 
;
; winusb device driver
; 
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Version]
Signature       = "$Windows NT$"
Class           = Products
ClassGuid       = {78A1C341-4539-11d3-B88D-00C04FAD5171}
Provider        = %ProviderName%
DriverVer       = 25/07/2011,1.0.1
;DriverPackageType=PlugAndPlay
DriverPackageDisplayName=%DESC%
;CatalogFile=MyCatFile.cat

; ================== Class section ===================

[ClassInstall32]
AddReg      = ClassInstall_AddReg

[ClassInstall_AddReg]
HKR,,,0,%ClassName%
HKR,,Icon,,-1

; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========

[Manufacturer]
%ProviderName%  = Products,NTx86,NTx64

[Products.NTx86]
%USB\MyDevice.DeviceDesc% = USB_Install, USB\VID_21A2&PID_0100

[Products.NTx64]
%USB\MyDevice.DeviceDesc% = USB_Install, USB\VID_21A2&PID_0100

; =================== Installation ===================

[USB_Install]
Include     = winusb.inf
Needs       = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include     = winusb.inf
AddService  = WinUSB,0x00000002,WinUSB_ServiceInstall

[WinUSB_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUSB_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[USB_Install.Wdf]
KmdfService = WINUSB, WinUsb_Install

[WinUSB_Install]
KmdfLibraryVersion  = 1.11

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg      = Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{70cd8e5b-1a46-4418-a1a5-4489f4b4aa79}"

[USB_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg      = CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles   = CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
HKR,,CoInstallers32,0x00010000,"WdfCoInstaller01011.dll,WdfCoInstaller","WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll"

[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll
WdfCoInstaller01011.dll

[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

; ================= Source Media Section =====================

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\x86
2 = %DISK_NAME%,,,\x64

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll=1
WdfCoInstaller01011.dll=1

[SourceDisksFiles.x64]
WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll=2
WdfCoInstaller01011.dll=2


; =================== Strings ===================

[Strings]
ProviderName    = "Products"
ClassName   = "Ss"
USB\MyDevice.DeviceDesc = "Ppp"
WinUSB_SvcDesc  = "WinUSB Driver Service"
;DISK_NAME  = "USBDriverPackage"
DESC            = "Ppp"
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't a question. Please take some extra time to give some details and let us know what it is you want help with. Can you give us some more details please?

Comment: Need sample of inf file for driver package installation on 64 bit windows8 operating system .say for example

Comment: @krishnamrajuk I would recommend you to add your comment to your question, this would make more clear what you want.. and by the way, what I'm also wanting :)
Did you managed to get this sample inf file yet?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the .inf file works on Windows Vista/7 etc, I assume that it is fine! Unfortunately, on Windows 8 you need to sign the .inf file of the user side driver (winusb), if you want to access the device using Interface GUID as on Windows Vista/7.

You have three options:

1. Sign it. This link will be very helpful: http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/
2. Disable driver signature enforcement and then install the driver. You will need to follow this process only in order to install the driver. Then, you may restart your computer normally and the driver will be working fine because you don't install any Kernel side code -otherwise you would have had problems- http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/
3. If the device is for personal (development) use only, you can use the installation without .inf http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540283(v=vs.85).aspx

Cheers,

Christos

Comment: Installation in Windows 8 without an inf is not restricted to development/personal use.

Comment: @ajs410 You are right. It is not restricted to development use, I just do not consider it user-friendly.